# Reading a fixed number of chars with << on an istream

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream, filereader

I was trying out a few file reading strategies in C++ and I came across this.

```
ifstream ifsw1("c:\\trys\\str3.txt");
char ifsw1w[3];
do {
    ifsw1 >> ifsw1w;
    if (ifsw1.eof())
        break;
    cout << ifsw1w << flush << endl;
} while (1);
ifsw1.close();
```

The content of the file were

```
firstfirst firstsecond
secondfirst secondsecond
```

When I see the output it is printed as

```
 firstfirst
firstsecond
secondfirst
```

I expected the output to be something like:

```
fir
stf
irs
tfi
.....
```

Moreover I see that "secondsecond" has not been printed. I guess that the last read has met the eof and the cout might not have been executed. But the first behavior is not understandable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The extraction operator has no concept of the size of the ifsw1w variable, and (by default) is going to extract characters until it hits whitespace, null, or eof.  These are likely being stored in the memory locations after your ifsw1w variable, which would cause bad bugs if you had additional variables defined.

To get the desired behavior, you should be able to use

```
ifsw1.width(3);
```

to limit the number of characters to extract.

Comment: I'm not near my compiler, but according to the documentation here it should work: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: @irritate and what about, say, a hex string? That is suppose I have `istringstream s("12AB");` and I want to convert it to two `unsigned a,b;` variables so that `a` would equal 0x12 and `b` 0xAB. Probably this could be achieved by `s >> std::hex >> setw(2) >> a;` and then `s >> std::hex >> setw(2) >> b`. But this doesn't work since there is no appropriate `setw()` manipulator for an `istream`. And in this case `s.width(2)` does not help either. Is there a way to limit the number of parsed symbols?

Comment: @krokoziabla I came here looking for the answer to exactly this question and was saddened to find no one had answered you.

Answer (score 2):

You're trashing the memory... its reading past the 3 chars you defined (its reading until a space or a new line is met...).

Read char by char to achieve the output you had mentioned.

Edit : Irritate is right, this works too (with some fixes and not getting the exact result, but that's the spirit):

```
char ifsw1w[4];
    do{
        ifsw1.width(4);
        ifsw1 >> ifsw1w;
        if(ifsw1.eof()) break;
        cout << ifsw1w << flush << endl;
    }while(1);
    ifsw1.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It's virtually impossible to use `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, char *)` safely -- it's like `gets` in this regard -- there's no way for you to specify the buffer size. The stream just writes to your buffer, going off the end. (Your example above invokes undefined behavior). Either use the overloads accepting a `std::string`, or use `std::getline(std::istream&, std::string)`.
2. Checking `eof()` is incorrect. You want `fail()` instead. You really don't care if the stream is at the end of the file, you care only if you have failed to extract information.

For something like this you're probably better off just reading the whole file into a string and using string operations from that point. You can do that using a stringstream:

```
#include <string> //For string
#include <sstream> //For stringstream
#include <iostream> //As before

std::ifstream myFile(...);
std::stringstream ss;
ss << myFile.rdbuf(); //Read the file into the stringstream.
std::string fileContents = ss.str(); //Now you have a string, no loops!
```

Answer (score 2):

The code has undefined behavior. When you do something like this:

```
char ifsw1w[3];

ifsw1 >> ifsw1w;
```

The `operator>>` receives a *pointer* to the buffer, but has no idea of the buffer's actual size. As such, it has no way to know that it should stop reading after two characters (and note that it should be 2, not 3 -- it needs space for a `'\0'` to terminate the string).

Bottom line: in your exploration of ways to read data, this code is probably best ignored. About all you can learn from code like this is a few things you should avoid. It's generally easier, however, to just follow a few rules of thumb than try to study all the problems that can arise.

1. Use `std::string` to read strings.
2. Only use fixed-size buffers for fixed-size data.
3. When you do use fixed buffers, pass their size to limit how much is read.
4. When you want to read all the data in a file, `std::copy` can avoid a lot of errors:

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> strings;   
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(myFile),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::back_inserter(strings));
   ```

Comment: By the 3rd option, are you talking about the width() option ?

Comment: @bsoundra: the width option is one, calling `read` is another.

Answer (score 1):

To read the whitespace, you could used "noskipws", it will not skip whitespace.

```
ifsw1 >> noskipws >> ifsw1w;
```

But if you want to get only 3 characters, I suggest you to use the get method:

```
ifsw1.get(ifsw1w,3);
```

Comment: ifstream ifsw2("c:\\trys\\str3.txt");
     char ifsw2w[3];
     do{
         ifsw2.get(ifsw2w,2);
         if(ifsw2.eof()) break;
         cout << ifsw2w  << flush << endl
     }while(1);
    if(ifsw2w != NULL)
         cout<< ifsw2w <<endl<<flush;
     ifsw2.close();`

This code just printed the first line . That too char-by-char. Then it goes into infinite loop printing null. I tried to make the above look in code format, but it is not appearing so. please help me with this.